# When does a noun accept an adjectivization? Does "Autor" accept one?

Tags: single-word-request

I'd like to transform

> Text von drei Autoren

into

> 3-[adjective for Autor+*er*] Text.

I tried with *autoriger* but I find it in no dictionary. Which is the correct form?

**Edit**: Thanks to Ingo, I think it is more interesting to ask

*When does a noun accept an "adjectivization"?*

Comment: First off, it must read "Autor" if I am not mistaken.

Comment: On [canoo.net](http://www.canoo.net/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-A/N-To-A/Suffig.html?lang=en) you find possible suffixes. But I'm afraid for your purpose you'll cannot find a valid one.

Comment: If it really has to be then I would say "Der 3-Autoren-Text". Yap. 2 hyphens in one noun. Haters gonna hate.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide more context. I am almost sure that "Der Text dreier Autoren ..." would be better. "3-Autoren-Text" appears clumsy to me.

Comment: c.p. With reference to your recent changes to the question, see my comments to the answer. I could imagine that my comments covers your question, so I would convert it into an answer, if you think it belongs there.

Comment: @Em1 I think it does. But I also see the point of Ingo, which (as I understand it) is not happy with this question having an *ist-* explanation, because *sein* is not the only verb you can use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually wouldn't call `autorig` or `dreiautorig` wrong without questioning. The fact, that it's not present in our dictionaries doesn't make it downright wrong. There are much more worse words that **are** present in those and this one seems to be theoretically correct.

Go with it, it's absolutely fine in my opinion but you maybe should try to find a way around it.

Answer (score 2):

In German we don't have the possibility to create an adjective out of every noun. The Word

> autorig

does not exist. The correct way to express what you want so say is how you already mentioned:

> Text von drei Autoren

There are few possibilities where you can create an adjectiv out of a noun, for example

> Eine neunschwänzige Katze (A cat with nine tails)

But don't try this with "Autor" ;) Most Germans will get what you mean, but it is wrong.

Comment: I agree with you that we shouldn't say "3-autorig". Yet I am not sure it is exactly wrong - it seems formally correct, when we compare "5-seitiger Text" , "3-sprachiger Text". An interesting question is why we can adjectivise some properties, but not others.

Comment: For example "dreibeinige Katze", "einäugige Katze" is ok, but not something like "zweibesitzige Katze" (a cat that has 2 owners).

Comment: @Ingo Mit dem zweiten Kommentar gibst du schon die Beispiele. Die Erklärung ist etwa: Handelt es sich um eine Ist-Beziehung, so hast du ein prädikatives Adjektiv und kannst es folglich auch attributiv darstellen. "Die Katze ist dreibeinig. => eine 3-beinige Katze" "Der Text ist dreisprachig. => Ein drei-sprachiger Text" - In allen anderen Fällen ist dies nicht möglich. In "Der Text ist von 3 Autoren == Der Text gehört 3 Autoren" ist "von 3 Autoren" kein Adjektiv (sondern eine Prepositonalphrase) und somit kannst du auch kein Attribut bilden.

Comment: @Ingo Um ein wenig penible zu sein: Genau genommen ist ein Text nicht 3-sprachig. Und somit gibt es keinen "3-sprachigen Text". Oder hast du schon mal einen Text gesehen, der 3 Sprachen beherrscht. Der Text besteht auf 3 Seiten und ist somit "ein aus 3 Sprachen bestehender Text" und ein Text von 3 Autoren ist demnach "ein von 3 Autoren geschriebener Text".

Comment: @Em1 Danke für deine Erklärung, die ich jeoch nicht ganz befriedigend finde. Du sagts im Prinzip: Wenn "X ist y-ig" geht, dann auch "y-ig X", aber es handelt sich ja gerade darum, warum "der Text is 3-autorig" anscheinend nicht geht.

Comment: @Ingo Genau das ist der Punkt den ich gerade noch kurz vor dir angefügt habe. Ein Text ist nicht dreiautorig. Er ist geschrieben von 3 Autoren. Er ist von drei Autoren. Er gehört meinetwegen 3 Autoren. Aber er ist nicht 3-autorig, weder attributiv noch prädikativ.

Comment: Ok, @Em1, es scheint in der Tat mit "haben" oder "sein" zu tun  zu haben. Das Dumme daran ist nur, daß man all diese Beziehungen auch mit "haben" ausdrücken kann (Die Katze hat 3 Beine. Der Text hat 3 Autoren.) Daher dann wohl die Verwirrung. Aber bei einem muß ich dir widersprechen: n-sprachig heißt nicht ausschließlich, daß das bezeichnete Objekt n Sprachen sprechen muß (und somit nur ein Mensch sein kann). Zumindest findet Google für mich über 800.000 Vorkommen von "zweisprachige Bücher", und dies scheint mir eine durchaus gängige Verwendung zu sein.

Comment: @Ingo Good catch. Wie eingeleitet, ich war ein wenig penibel dort. Semantisch gesehen entspricht "ein 3-sprachiger Text" == "ein Text bestehend aus 3 Sprachen" bzw. "wird in 3 Sprachen zur Verfügung gestellt" und nicht "Ein Text kann 3 Sprachen". Daher hast du recht. Um es kurz nochmals zu erwähnen, weil du es ansprichst. Während eine Katze 3 Beine hat (besteht aus), kann ein Text nicht 3 Autoren 'besitzen'. Die Sperre ist hier weniger die Grammatik, sondern die Semantik.

Comment: @Em1 Richtig, "Das Buch hat 3 Autoren." ist strenggenommen kein gutes Deutsch, auch wenn die Katze aus mehr als nur 3 Beinen besteht, hoffentlich :)